# Как установить последюю версию monodevelop на debian?

Tags: monodevelop, debian

По умолчанию ставится старая версия (как более стабильная видимо), как установить свежую версию monodevelop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

либо скачать с тестового зеркала, либо подключить тестовые репозитарий, последний способ предпочтительней, ибо зависимости подтянутся автоматом.
для домашнего использования, не вижу смысла пользовать стабильную ветку debian

Comment: добавляем  строку в /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://ftp.ru.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main

apt-get install synaptic

в синаптике ищем моно и монодевлоп последних версий, устанавливаем.